# Trying to concatenate multiple pem files into one using openssl 'cat' command

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm seeing in multiple places that the "cat" openssl command can be used to concatenate multiple pem files into one.  I've seen a couple versions of syntax:

cat first_cert.pem second_cert.pem > combined_cert.pem
cat *.pem > combinedpem.pem

But I keep getting "Invalid command 'cat'; type "help" for a list."   And "cat" isn't in the list (including list below).

I'm using OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl with a lastmodified date of 9/26/2016.

Thanks in advance!

C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl help

Standard commands
asn1parse         ca                ciphers           cms
crl               crl2pkcs7         dgst              dhparam
dsa               dsaparam          ec                ecparam
enc               engine            errstr            exit
gendsa            genpkey           genrsa            help
list              nseq              ocsp              passwd
pkcs12            pkcs7             pkcs8             pkey
pkeyparam         pkeyutl           prime             rand
rehash            req               rsa               rsautl
s_client          s_server          s_time            sess_id
smime             speed             spkac             srp
ts                verify            version           x509

Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4
md5               mdc2              rmd160            sha1
sha224            sha256            sha384            sha512

Cipher commands (see the `enc' command for more details)
aes-128-cbc       aes-128-ecb       aes-192-cbc       aes-192-ecb
aes-256-cbc       aes-256-ecb       base64            bf
bf-cbc            bf-cfb            bf-ecb            bf-ofb
camellia-128-cbc  camellia-128-ecb  camellia-192-cbc  camellia-192-ecb
camellia-256-cbc  camellia-256-ecb  cast              cast-cbc
cast5-cbc         cast5-cfb         cast5-ecb         cast5-ofb
des               des-cbc           des-cfb           des-ecb
des-ede           des-ede-cbc       des-ede-cfb       des-ede-ofb
des-ede3          des-ede3-cbc      des-ede3-cfb      des-ede3-ofb
des-ofb           des3              desx              idea
idea-cbc          idea-cfb          idea-ecb          idea-ofb
rc2               rc2-40-cbc        rc2-64-cbc        rc2-cbc
rc2-cfb           rc2-ecb           rc2-ofb           rc4
rc4-40            seed              seed-cbc          seed-cfb
seed-ecb          seed-ofb

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Try (for instance) cygwin, the command shell implements all the regular posix commands, including `cat` and, of course, `openssl`. The shell is pretty good as well too, you'll soon forget the regular command shell, except possibly in a nightmare now and then.